# Calling a javascript function after loading all scripts in vue

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to use Vue to achieve what I did in VanillaJS.

I used beforeMount() to load all the scripts related to the element and then called the function that initiates it. But it still says

`CodeMirror is not defined`

This is my code below

```
Test = {};

Test.VueComponents = {

init: function () {

    // Vue vootstrap toggle input, effectively a re-styled checkbox
    Vue.component('test', {
        template: '<div class="form-group"><label>Basic styles</label><textarea id="basic" name="basic"></textarea></div>',
        mounted: function() {
            console.log('mounted');

        },
        ready() {
              this.InitiateCodeMirror();  
        },
         beforeMount(){
            this.Script1();
            this.Script2();
            this.Script3();
            this.Script4();
            this.Script5();
            this.Script6();
            this.Script7();
         },
        methods: {
            Script1: function() {
              return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
               let script = document.createElement('script')
               script.setAttribute('src','../../../../../codemirror/lib/codemirror.js')
               console.log("S1")
               document.head.appendChild(script)
              })
             },
             Script2: function() {
              return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
               let script = document.createElement('script')
                                  script.setAttribute('href','../../../../../codemirror/lib/codemirror.css')
               console.log("S2")
               document.head.appendChild(script)
              })
             },
             Script3: function() {
              return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
               let script = document.createElement('script')
               script.setAttribute('href','../../../../../codemirror/addon/hint/show-hint.css')

               console.log("S3")
               document.head.appendChild(script)
              })
             },
             Script4: function() {
              return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
               let script = document.createElement('script')
               script.setAttribute('src','../../../../../codemirror/mode/css/css.js')
               console.log("S4")
               document.head.appendChild(script)
              })
             },
             Script5: function() {
              return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
               let script = document.createElement('script')
               script.setAttribute('src','../../../../../codemirror/addon/hint/show-hint.js')
               console.log("S5")
               document.head.appendChild(script)
              })
             },
             Script6: function() {
              return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
               let script = document.createElement('script')
               script.setAttribute('src','../../../../../codemirror/addon/hint/css-hint.js')
               console.log("S6")
               document.head.appendChild(script)
              })
             },
             Script7: function() {
              return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
               let script = document.createElement('script')
               script.setAttribute('src','../../../../../codemirror/mode/css/scss_test.js')
               console.log("S7")
               document.head.appendChild(script)
              })
             },

             InitiateCodeMirror: function() {
                var myCodeMirror = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("basic"), {
                    lineNumbers: true,
                    indentUnit: 4
                });
                var myCodeMirror = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("media"), {
                        lineNumbers: true,
                        indentUnit: 4
                });
            }
        },
    });
}
}

$(document).ready(function(){
console.log('ready')
Test.VueComponents.init();
});
```

Though the console logs of S1 S2 S3 I have written inside each script call is shown in console and scripts are also loaded when inspected in Network tab.

Comment: Could this be because of the asynchronous manner (e.g. Promises) that you are loading your code?

Comment: Don't know man! I have just started Vue and should I be using Promise or not.

Comment: Why don't you load the Codemirror by tag <script> ?

Comment: https://github.com/surmon-china/vue-codemirror